# Active admin customize filter only specific attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, filter, customization, activeadmin

I have active admin integrated to my app. In Users section the filter is having too many attributes and if I have to customize one the condition in the filter I have to re-write the entire filter again. Can someone suggest me a way to modify a specific condition of the filter than rewriting the entire filter. I want to modify condition for Names list from the attachment.

Like here I have to re-write all the conditions for the filter, instead I want to update a specific filter condition

```
 filter :website_users
  filter :identities
  filter :names, :collection => proc {(Name.all).map{|c| [c.text, c.id]}}
  filter :competitions
  filter :suggested_names, :collection => proc {(Name.all).map{|c| [c.text, c.id]}}
```

[Filter with conditions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNWJq.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
preserve_default_filters! # build the default filters
remove_filter :website_users # remove a default filter
filter :names, collection: proc { Name.all.map{ |c| [c.text, c.id] } }
```

Comment: I think `collection: -> { Name.pluck(:text, :id) }` would be faster when it comes to big amount o data, but it is rather a note to OP :)

Comment: How about removing filters like email contains, startswith, endswith, date range ?

Comment: I want to remove default filters like created_at, updated_at.

Comment: `remove_filter : created_at`